# EditorForModel displays inherited properties last

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, editorformodel

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC web app that includes a parts list. Because of this I have created a class hierarchy. The problem I have is that using `Html.EditorForModel()` displays the properties from the inherited base class last when I want them to be displayed first.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

**Part.cs**

```
public class Part
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DiplayValue = false)]
    public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

**Screw.cs**

```
public class Screw : Part
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

Then when I call `Html.EditorForModel` in my View this is the order the fields show up in:

- Length
- Width
- Price
- Brand

But I want it to show up in this order:

- Price
- Brand
- Length
- Width

I've tried specifying the `[Column(Order = #)]` attribute but that didn't change anything. Outside of creating an EditorTemplate for each Part, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Display` attribute to set order:

```
[Display(Order = 2)]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Display(Order = 1)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```